# Javascript EventListener on button does not work

Tags: javascript, button, addeventlistener

I tried make `button` on `HTML` using `Javascript`
and tried to make button having `EventListener`

here is code :

```
function addRefresh(){
 var buildButton = `<button id = "refreshBtn"> testBtn </button>
 <script>
    document.getElementById('refreshBtn').addEventListener("click",function() {alert('hi'););
 </script>
 `
  document.getElementsByClassName('f_l')[0].innerHTML += buildButton;
}
```

html on website :

```
<span class="f_l">
    <button id="refreshBtn"> testBtn </button>
    <script>
     document.getElementById('refreshBtn').addEventListener("click",function() {alert('hi'););
    </script>
</span>
```

but when i click button Event doesn't occur.

I've tried `button onclick="myFunction()"` also.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: function() {alert('hi');); --> you forget a } for your function

Comment: there was mistake on rewriting on StackOverflow.
actual code is fine

Comment: actual code  
     
`document.getElementById('refreshBtn').addEventListener("click",function() {alert('hi');});`

Comment: it's work for me please remove cache of your browser or reopen file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do following and it works fine.

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <span class="f_l"></span>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

**main.js**

```
function addRefresh() {

     var buildButton = `<button id="refreshBtn"> testBtn </button>`;
     document.getElementsByClassName("f_l")[0].innerHTML += buildButton;
     document.getElementById('refreshBtn').addEventListener("click",function() {alert("Hi");});
}

addRefresh();
```

**Why?**

- DRY: Do not need to add button via both html and via JS.
- Add event listener in main.js itself instead of through `<script>` tag. I think @dev_Fares may be right(

  > you can't write the script inside the inner html

).

Answer (score 2):

You miss one carley braces in:

```
  document.getElementById('refreshBtn').addEventListener("click",function() {alert('hi'););
```

change it to:

```
  document.getElementById('refreshBtn').addEventListener("click",function() {alert('hi')});
```

Comment: there was mistake on rewriting on StackOverflow. actual code is fine  actual code :`document.getElementById('refreshBtn').addEventListener("click",function() {alert('hi');});` sorry for mistake

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't write the script inside the inner html and you repet it in the html code so there is no need for it inside the js code

```
function addRefresh()
{ 
var buildButton = '<button id = "refreshBtn"> testBtn </button>';
document.getElementsByClassName('f_l')[0].innerHTML += buildButton;
}
```